# tract_choropleth throws error when used with reference_path=TRUE; similar code works at state, county and zip level

Tags: r, choroplethr

I am attempting to create a basic census tract choropleth with map overlay through setting parameter reference_map=TRUE:

```
library(choroplethr)
library(choroplethrMaps)
library(choroplethrZip)
library(ggmap)

data(df_pop_ny_tract)
tract_choropleth(df_pop_ny_tract,state_name="new york",num_colors=1
                             ,reference_map=TRUE)
```

Which when run throws this error:

```
Error in if (lon < -180 || lon > 180) cli::cli_abort("Longitude of center must be between -180 and 180 degrees. Note {.pkg ggmap} uses lon/lat, not lat/lon."): missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

reference_map=TRUE works fine with other levels of choropleths, from state all the way to zip, once I registered with Google and followed the solution posted here: [bug when creating reference maps with choroplethr](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/05/bug-when-creating-reference-maps-with-choroplethr/).
For example, the analogous choroplethr call at the zip level produces the choropleth with map overlay:

```
library(choroplethr)
library(choroplethrMaps)
library(choroplethrZip)
library(ggmap)

data(df_pop_zip)
 zip_choropleth(df_pop_zip,state_zoom=c("new york")
                ,num_colors=1
                 ,reference_map=TRUE)
```

[output map from zip_choropleth with reference_map=TRUE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oCzD.jpg)

The tract_choropleth also works fine where reference_map=FALSE

```
library(choroplethr)
library(choroplethrMaps)
library(choroplethrZip)
library(ggmap)

data(df_pop_ny_tract)
tract_choropleth(df_pop_ny_tract,state_name="new york",num_colors=1
                             ,reference_map=FALSE)
```

[output map from tract_choropleth with reference_map=FALSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzeTh.png)

My environment is:

```
## R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31)
## Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
## Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
## 
## Matrix products: default
## BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.10.0 
## LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.10.0
## 
## locale:
##  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
##  [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
##  [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
##  [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
##  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
## [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
## 
## time zone: America/New_York
## tzcode source: system (glibc)
## 
## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
## 
## other attached packages:
## [1] ggmap_4.0.0           ggplot2_3.4.4         choroplethrZip_1.5.0 
## [4] choroplethrMaps_1.0.1 choroplethr_3.7.2     acs_2.1.4            
## [7] XML_3.99-0.16.1       stringr_1.5.1         knitr_1.45           
##
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of what `df_pop_ny_tract` and `df_pop_zip` look like? The `reference_map` argument seems to use `ggmap` to grab a basemap from Google, which likely has a different coordinate reference system (CRS) than your census tract data ( `choroplethr` makes use of the `tigris` package in the background to grab the shapefile, so you should be able to check the CRS of `df_pop_ny_tract` using `sf::st_crs(df_pop_ny_tract)`.

Comment: Thanks, the images should be in the links labelled "output map from ..."  Please let me know if they are visible to you, or if there is a better way to embed images. thanks

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that upon examining the source code of `choroplethr`, the problem is likely caused by differing map projections between `df_pop_ny_tract` (which has a geodetic CRS = NAD 83 / EPSG: 4269) and the `reference_map` called inside of the `tract_choropleth()` function (which uses `ggmaps` in the background to return a basemap that has a geodetic CRS = WGS 84 & EPSG: 3857, aka Psuedo-Mercator).

All of this is complicated by the fact that `df_pop_ny_tract` is purely an object of the `data.frame` class. It's only during the call to the `tract_choropleth()` function that it's joined by `region` column to the `GEOID` column of the TIGER shapefile called internally by the `tigris` package, at which point it inherits that CRS. I think it may be easier to directly use many of the underlying packages to achieve your desired result instead of the `choroplethr` family of packages. Here's how I recreated your desired output using `sf`, `tidycensus`, `ggplot2`, and `ggmap`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(sf)
library(tidycensus)

# Recreate NY tract population
# Requires registering for free Census API key
df_ny_pop_tract <- tidycensus::get_decennial(
  geography = "tract",
  state = "NY",
  variables = c("Total Population" = "P1_001N"),
  geometry = TRUE,
  output = "tidy",
  sumfile = "pl"
)

# Get bounding box for use in ggmap function
# st_bbox(df_ny_pop_tract)

# Get reference map (from Google or Stadia Maps)
# Use get_googlemap() for Google
# I don't have a Google Maps API key so I use Stadia Maps
ny_reference_map <- ggmap::get_stadiamap(
  bbox = c(left = -79.76215, bottom = 40.49610, right = -71.85621, top = 45.01585),
  zoom = 10,
  maptype = "alidade_smooth"
)

# Draw map
ggmap(ny_reference_map) +
  geom_sf(data = df_ny_pop_tract, aes(fill = value), inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  theme_void()
```

[image: Choropleth of New York with reference map]

A key part of the code at the end is to specify `inherit.aes=FALSE` to deal with the different map projections. It's a different basemap since I don't have a Google Maps API key anymore, but you should be able to substitute a Google Maps basemap with `ggmap::get_googlemap()`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your helpful and complete answer which answers my question. Choroplethr is an amazing package and offers a lot of convenience, but it relies on lower-level libraries and functionality and the interfaces are always subject to change. 
Your advice to pierce the abstraction is very sound, and your example will definitely help me to do so! thank you again.